# libcurl Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c++, curl, valgrind

I understand from other questions on SO that this warning should not be taken lightly.

It appears to originate from the **curl_easy_perform** method.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>


std::string data;

size_t writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
{
    for (int c = 0; c<size*nmemb; c++)
    {
        data.push_back(buf[c]);
    }
    return size*nmemb;
}



int main( void )
{
  curl_global_init ( CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT );
  CURL * curl;
  CURLcode res;

  struct curl_slist * chunk = NULL;

  chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "X-Mashape-Authorization: XXXYYYYZZZZ" );
  curl = curl_easy_init ( ) ;

  if( curl )
  {
    std::string _query = "text=Hello";

    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://japerk-text-processing.p.mashape.com/tag/" );
    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, _query.c_str() );
    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeCallback );
    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L );

    #ifdef SKIP_PEER_VERIFICATION 
    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L );
    #endif

    #ifdef SKIP_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION 
    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L );
    #endif

    res = curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk );
    res = curl_easy_perform ( curl );   // BUG: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

    curl_slist_free_all( chunk );

    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      std::cerr << "curl_easy_perform() failed: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  curl_global_cleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

Running with valgrind

```
==4443== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4443== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4443== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4443== Command: ./CURLTest
==4443== 
==4443== Thread 2:
==4443== Syscall param sendmsg(mmsg[0].msg_hdr) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==4443==    at 0x59A170B: sendmmsg (sendmmsg.c:36)
==4443==    by 0x86652DE: __libc_res_nsend (res_send.c:1140)
==4443==    by 0x8662B8B: __libc_res_nquery (res_query.c:226)
==4443==    by 0x8663147: __libc_res_nquerydomain (res_query.c:582)
==4443==    by 0x8663746: __libc_res_nsearch (res_query.c:378)
==4443==    by 0xA2FFA35: _nss_dns_gethostbyname4_r (dns-host.c:314)
==4443==    by 0x597B631: gaih_inet (getaddrinfo.c:849)
==4443==    by 0x597EA13: getaddrinfo (getaddrinfo.c:2473)
==4443==    by 0x4E77483: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==4443==    by 0x4E82F73: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==4443==    by 0x4E8089A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==4443==    by 0x78F4E0D: start_thread (pthread_create.c:311)
==4443==  Address 0x9eeb020 is on thread 2's stack
==4443==                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
==4443== Thread 1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
==4443== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)                                                                                                                                                                     
==4443==    at 0x6304908: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)                                                                                                                                                            
==4443==    by 0x62FB572: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)                                                                                                                                                            
==4443==    by 0x62F8BF5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)                                                                                                                                                            
==4443==    by 0x4E57CAB: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)                                                                                                                                                           
==4443==    by 0x4E48C3A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)                                                                                                                                                           
==4443==    by 0x4E60832: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)                                                                                                                                                           
==4443==    by 0x4E6A917: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)                                                                                                                                                           
==4443==    by 0x4E6B070: curl_multi_perform (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)                                                                                                                                            
==4443==    by 0x4E62906: curl_easy_perform (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)                                                                                                                                             
==4443==    by 0x40130C: main (in /CURLTest/CURLTest)
```

- GCC 4.8.2
- valgrind 3.8.1
- libcurl 4.3.0

Could some please help?
Is this a false positive, can I ignore it or could it lead to problems?

Thanks

Comment: As a first step, can you try reducing the function? I mean you still have conditionsl compiled code, which certainly is not both executing and not.  What lines can be deleted while keeping the error?  http://sscce.org -- you can do this better than anyone reading this question, and ad it stands this is a useless question to anyone else.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. This is the offending code, seems to originate from curl_easy_perform. I'm surprised nobody has had a similar issue with curl before

Comment: I linked to a website, did you read it?  I asked you to delete all code that is not required to generate the error: this involves testing and deleting.  The goal is to habe an absolutely minimal program, with the fewest lines youmcan manage, with extraneous stuff gone, that generates the problem.  This both makes it easier for people to help you, and 90% of the time you bump into the answer before you are done, AND it means it is far more likely that what you ask will help others.

Comment: Yes I took a peek, wrote it in a main.cpp, still having the same output.